why do I get this error BindingError: Expected null or instance of Config,…act-pdf/renderer/lib/react-pdf.browser.js:4268:9
TLDR: Why do I get error of this, whenever I'm about to generate my pdf?
app-index.js:33 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'write')
    at PDFDocument.addContent (pdfkit.browser.js:46504:15)
    at PDFDocument.save (pdfkit.browser.js:9270:17)
    at renderNode (index.js:1897:7)
    at eval (index.js:1986:25)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at render (index.js:1986:9)
    at render (react-pdf.browser.js:4249:85)
    at async Object.toBlob (react-pdf.browser.js:4268:9)

And sometimes I get this error
BindingError: Expected null or instance of Config,…act-pdf/renderer/lib/react-pdf.browser.js:4268:9

I have a multi-form wherein i'm using react-hook-form and then with the use of form.watch(), I retrieve the data of it and pass it down to my appointmentdocument.tsx wherein it serves the actual design for my pdf file
main.tsx -> downloadbutton.tsx -> pdfdownload.tsx -> appointmentdocument.tsx
So it starts from this
main.tsx
<DownloadButton
    form={form}
/>

downloadbutton.tsx
'use client'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Loader2 } from 'lucide-react'

const PDFDownload = dynamic(
  () => import('./pdf-download-component'),
  { 
    loading: () => <Loader2 className='animate-spin' />,
    ssr: false
  }
)

const DownloadButton = ({ form }: any) => {
  const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setShowButton(true)
    }, 5000) // 3 seconds delay

    return () => clearTimeout(timer) // Cleanup timer on component unmount
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {showButton ? (
        <PDFDownload form={form} />
      ) : (
        <>
        <Loader2 className='animate-spin' />
        <p>Kindly wait, we're generating your pdf copy...</p>
        </>
        
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default DownloadButton

After that, I pass it down to this component.
const PDFDownload: React.FC<PDFDownloadProps> = ({ form }) => {
  return (
    <BlobProvider document={<AppointmentDocument form={form} />}>
      {({ blob, url, loading, error }) => {
        if (loading) {
          return (
            <Button variant="default" className='flex gap-2' type='button' size="sm" disabled>
              Loading document...
            </Button>
          )
        }

        if (error) {
          return (
            <Button variant="default" className='flex gap-2' type='button' size="sm" disabled>
              Error loading document
            </Button>
          )
        }

        return (
          <Button
            variant="default"
            className='flex gap-2'
            type='button'
            size="sm"
            onClick={() => {
              const link = document.createElement('a')
              //@ts-ignore
              link.href = url
              link.download = 'Appointment_Schedule.pdf'
              link.click()
            }}
          >
            <Download />
            <p>Appointment, download PDF copy</p>
          </Button>
        )
      }}
    </BlobProvider>
  )
}

export default PDFDownload

And then, I pass it down once again to AppointmentDocument.tsx, this is where I handle all of the styling for my document types.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Document, Page, Text, View, Image, StyleSheet, Font } from '@react-pdf/renderer';
import { Loader2 } from 'lucide-react';

// Assume these are imported correctly
import CUSTOMLOGO_1 from '@/public/sample_logo.png';
import CUSTOMLOGO2 from '@/public/logo2.png';
import { format } from 'date-fns';

// Register fonts (you'll need to provide the correct paths to your font files)


// Create styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    padding: 30,
  },
  header: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 20,
    borderBottom: '1 solid #000',
    paddingBottom: 10,
  },
  logo: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  },
  headerText: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
  main: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  subtitle: {
    fontSize: 12,
    marginBottom: 3,
  },
  email: {
    fontSize: 10,
    color: '#666',
  },

  //Content Main Header Date to Webinar
  content: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },


  labelAnswerContent: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  labelAnswer: {
    fontSize: 14,
    paddingLeft: 2
  }

});

const AppointmentDocument = ({ form }: any) => {

  
  const event_date = form.watch('event_date')
  const formattedDate = format(event_date, 'MMMM dd yyyy');

  const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsClient(true);
  }, []);

  if (!isClient) {
    return <Loader2 className="animate-spin" />;
  }

  return (
    <Document>
      <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Image src={CUSTOMLOGO_1.src} style={styles.logo} />
          <View style={styles.headerText}>
            <Text style={styles.main}>Trinity University Of Asia</Text>
            <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Trinitian Center for Education and Technology</Text>
            <Text style={styles.email}>tua@edu.ph</Text>
          </View>
          <Image src={CUSTOMLOGO2.src} style={styles.logo} />
        </View>

        <View >
          <View>
            <Text>Date of event: </Text>
            <Text>{formattedDate}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>

      </Page>
    </Document>
  );
};


export default AppointmentDocument


const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setIsClient(true);
}, []);

if (!isClient) {
  return <Loader2 className="animate-spin" />;
}

In AppointmentDocument, Loader2 component is being returned first time since initial state of isClient is false which causes the error.
if you need the condition for whatever reason then move it to the PDFDownload component and conditionally render BlobProvider.
